# Is it possible to keep/not mangle named anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

We started using errorception on our website to track down errors that happen in the wild, and I am giving named anonymous functions a go (http://kangax.github.io/nfe/)

Basically the goal is to have useful stack traces and give names to anonymous functions/callbacks like so:

```js
// anonymous function/callback with no name
$('#some_element').on('click', function(e) {
    // do something
});

// give the anonymous function/callback a name that appears in the stack trace
$('#some_element').on('click', function _name_to_appear_in_st(e) {
    // do something
});
```

So I am trying to keep the name (in this example "_name_to_appear_in_st") of the anonymous function in the minified code.  I am using grunt/uglify, and tried passing mangle: false to the options, but the names aren't there.  Is there a best way to go about this?

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem that might be solved with source maps.

Comment: So you're saying that the names of the functions are completely removed, or mangled (despite the `mangle: false` option)? The former would be pretty shocking.

Comment: *"...I am giving named anonymous functions..."* No, by definition a named function isn't anonymous (anonymous = without name). You're giving *named function expressions* a go, which is fine in a post-IE8 world (don't do it with IE8, [it gets them wrong](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html)). But beware: IE8 **still** has somewhere between an 11% and 15% global market share depending on who you ask, thanks to people hanging onto XP. The only stats that matter are stats for *your* site, of course, but...

Comment: You are right that they are "named function expressions" (thought I had called it that, but didn't (whoops).  And you are correct that IE 8 gets them wrong, and the names you give them will become variables/symbols in the current scope (or possibly global scope, since it isn't doing it correctly), but that is why I am going to name them accordingly (basically _nfe_customname)

Comment: and to Crowder, yes... the mangle option set to false still removes those names :-\

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. Set the compress option called `unused` to `false`.

```
options: {
  mangle: false,
  beautify: true,
  compress: { unused: false }
}
```

The Grunt [Uglify options documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#options) does not list the various compress options, but it says  you can pass options to the underlying UglifyJS compressor. Here is the full list of [UglifyJS2 Compressor options](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compressor-options).

Comment: This does keep the named function expression names, thanks!  Do you know if there is a way to still mangle the names, including the named function expressions, and have them available in the sourcemaps?  Like normal variable names are handled in sourcemaps?  This way can still keep the size down, but still accomplish my goal?

Comment: Yes, The mangle/compress settings will not affect the sourcemaps. You will see your named function expression when debugging in Chrome/Firebox, etc.

Comment: I guess my issue is, that while in the sourcemap, you will see the name, and where it happened in your code, I need the name in the stacktrace, because we are using errorception, and for certain browsers (even though it supports hidden sourcemaps, and works for the most part), I need the name in the actual trace, which is outside the scope of the sourcemaps.  Would be awesome to be able to mangle varibable/function names except be able to accept something like a prefix or a regex, so you can mangle the code, with the exception of stuff matching the regex/prefix